# Where is the style for background-color on menu layout?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-community

When you create a new MVC project in Visual Studio you get this layout:

[image]

If you click inspect on the jumbotron (ASP.NET container) you get this class on the style:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 2.1428571435;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Where it have `background-color` definition as `#eeeeee` and is in fact that gray color you see above.

But if you inspect the About button, there is nothing about the `background-color` only a inheritance of the `body` but that is a white color `#ffffff`. I use a color picker tool and found out the blackish color is in fact `#222222` but I don't see it on the inspect code.

So where is define the `background-color` for the menu layout?

[image]

Comment: That style is called bootstrap, v3.x. have a google, might help.

Comment: @Adriani6 Something specific about bootstrap I should looks for? bootstrap is a library not a style. And also doesnt answer why one element show it and other doesnt.

Answer (score -2):

I bet the styles for the background-color are on the navbar-nav class. As the chrome inspector only displays styles applied to the selected element, it will not display the background-color, which is only applied to the parent.

Comment: And this at most a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The chrome tab only shows styles that apply to the element inspecting. The background-color set to the navbar-nav element is not applied to the inspected element.

Comment: Agree, should have been a comment. Sorry :/

Comment: Or improve the answer. But ty will try to see the parent elements.

Comment: Improved the answer now